# About factors of tensor products

Tags: commutative-algebra

Given $A,B,C$ Modules over a commutative ring $R$ when I can say that $A \otimes C \simeq B\otimes C\Rightarrow A\simeq B$?

Comment: When $C\cong R$?

Comment: Obviously i don’t need a complete list of the cases but as much cases as possible..

Comment: when $C$ is a faithfully flat $R$-module ?